# Where to set state, dependent on previous and current props, in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I was using the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle event to enable or disable transition to the next page. Now that this event is changed to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`, I feel like I shouldn't use it anymore, however I couldn't find an obvious replacement for it.

The location of the component comes from `props.location.pathname`, so I'd need an event, where I can access both the previous and next props and then set the initial appearance of the component depending on if there should be transition or not, however:

- `getDerivedStateFromProps` only has access to the previous props.
- `shouldComponentUpdate` should be used for telling the component if it should update or not, which is not what we want, so it's out.
- `render` doesn't have the previous props.
- `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` passes the parameter to `componentDidUpdate`, at which point the component is already rendered, so I can't set the initial apprearance.

I guess I could save the previous pathname and use that the next time in `render`, but this doesn't seem like an elegant solution. What is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that

```
getDerivedStateFromProps only has access to the previous props.
```

But getDerivedStateFromProps has access to next props and previous state

Saving the previous pathname may not seem elegant, I agree, but it is an alternative offered here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjyvp7l3rq found here https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html.

Take a look at the uncontrolledEmailInput component saving prev props in state

```
state = {
    email: this.props.defaultEmail,
    prevPropsUserID: this.props.userID
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Any time the current user changes,
    // Reset any parts of state that are tied to that user.
    // In this simple example, that's just the email.
    if (props.userID !== state.prevPropsUserID) {
      return {
        prevPropsUserID: props.userID,
        email: props.defaultEmail
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Here is a great article about the new lifecycles: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-react-16-3-component-life-cycle-23129bc7a705

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the best solution then. I still don't like it though as you'll have an additional state just for checking the previous path.

Comment: Hi, How you could initiate a state with previous route path if in the constructor we already get the latest route path in `props.location.pathname`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below which is Safe and recommend by Reactjs

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 

     if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {

        this.fetchData(this.props.userID); 

    }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this re-render the component and cause flickering if the appearance of the page changes? I'm doing a full background transition here, so the whole page would update if didn't get the initial state right.

Comment: Right complete component will get rerender so I don't think flickering will occur.

Answer (score 0):

As per react documentation you should use componentDidUpdate. It has access to prevProps, prevState and current props, state in this.props, this.state.

Take a look at the documentation 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.pathname !== prevProps.pathname) {
      //do something here or setState to adjust the appearance accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll ask you what I asked the other person, who had the same answer: "Wouldn't this re-render the component and cause flickering if the appearance of the page changes? I'm doing a full background transition here, so the whole page would update if didn't get the initial state right."